# Dovecot: mark messages loaded over POP3 as read

Tags: email, dovecot, pop3

The task is to make messages delivered over POP3 marked **as read** while also **keep them on server** (even if `DELE` command issued by client) and accessible over IMAP.

There are two exim config options:

- `pop3_no_flag_updates = no` - this enables setting read flag on message
- `pop3_deleted_flag = "$POP3Deleted"` - this changes pop3 behavior so instead of message removal it just get flagged.

The strange thing is that following scenarios **work**:

- messages delivered over POP3 (`RETR` command) but not deleted by mail client during POP3-session (when it has special, client-side mode "preserving emails on server") - and these messages **are marked as read, FINE**
- messages deleted by mail client (using `DELE` command) are marked as "$POP3Deleted" - **GOOD**
- messages deleted by mail client during next POP3-session (previously marked as read) become marked as read **and** $POP3Deleted. OK

**BUT**: When standard POP3 message retrieval scheme takes place, and message fetched and deleted during single session it does not get marked as read but only $POP3Deleted

Why? Is it possible to change? (Dovecot version 2.3.7.2)